# Checkbox validation

Tags: magento2, form-validation, checkbox

[image]

I want Checkbox required field

I agree to the Terms and Conditions.

I am using this code but it's not working.

Comment: Have you added terms and conditions on the checkout page?

Comment: i want in registration page

Comment: Okay, I will give one code You can add.

Answer (score 0):

==>Overide Layout Your own module This file `customer_account_create.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Form\Optin" name="gdpr.account.addoptin"
                template="Vendor_Module::account/optin.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

==> After Layout Made You Made Optin.php Block your own Module

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Optin extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $personnalizedSuggestions = false;

    /**
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $thirdParty = false;

    /**
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $helper;

    /**
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getTermsConditionUrl()
    {
        $store_code = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        ==> Specify your store code 
        if ($store_code == 'en') {
        ==> Specify your store wise URL 
            $termsConditionUrl = "terms-and-conditions";
        }
        return $termsConditionUrl;
    }

    public function getPrivacyCookiesUrl()
    {
        $store_code = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        ==> Specify your store code 
        if ($store_code == 'en') {
        ==> Specify your store wise URL 
            $privacyCookiesUrl = "privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode_en";
        }
        return $privacyCookiesUrl;
    }

}
```

==>After Made Optin block Made optin.phtml file your own module.

```
<div id="gdpr-personnalized-suggestions-box" class="field choice gdpr required">
        <input type="checkbox" name="personnalized_suggestions" class="checkbox" id="account-form-personnalized-suggestions" class="input-text " data-validate="{required:true}" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Accept user personnalization') ?>" checked="checked" />
        <label for="account-form-personnalized-suggestions" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('I agree to the terms and conditions') ?></span></label>
        <span class="tooltip wrapper">
            <a class="link tooltip toggle" href="<?php echo $block->geturl($block->getTermsConditionUrl());?>" target="_blank"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What\'s this?') ?></a>
            <span class="tooltip content">
                <?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check this to access personnalized search result and suggestions based on your own history.')?>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>


<div id="gdpr-third-party-box" class="field choice gdpr required">
        <input type="checkbox" name="third_party" class="checkbox" id="account-form-third-party" data-validate="{required:true}" value="1" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Accept third party transmission') ?>" checked="checked" />
        <label for="account-form-third-party" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('I agree with the processing of personal data') ?></span></label>
        <span class="tooltip wrapper">
            <a class="link tooltip toggle" href="<?php echo $block->geturl($block->getPrivacyCookiesUrl());?>" target="_blank"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('What\'s this?') ?></a>
            <span class="tooltip content">
                <?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Check this to accept third party transmission.')?>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

After Made optin.phtml check it.